# Trying to activate jaspershen/MSannotator package in R

Tags: r, package

I am trying to work with some commands from "jaspershen/MSannotator"  package.
I tried to install the package:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("jaspershen/MSannotator")
library(remotes)
```

But not commands from package "jaspershen/MSannotator" appears.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add more packages for it to work:

```
devtools::install_github('omegahat/XMLSchema');devtools::install_github('cran/SSOAP')
BiocManager::install("Rdisop")
BiocManager::install("GO.db")

library(Rdisop)
library(xMSannotator)
```